# Play Framework Ebean delete without @Id

Tags: playframework, ebean

I have a model having two fields without any field with @Id field, i.e. no id field. Before exploring other ways, I was wondering whether it is possible call `obj.delete()` method on `Model`s which does not have a id field.

FYI it is showing *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not deleteById on models.DummyObject as no @Id property*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ebean's models requires `@Id` field in many places for finding the objects, and that should be unique (i.e. autoincrement numeric type).

If you don't have any you need to delete them with custom query:

```
import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.SqlUpdate;

...

SqlUpdate tangoDown = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("DELETE FROM tango WHERE foo = :foo AND bar = :bar");
tangoDown.setParameter("foo", 1);
tangoDown.setParameter("bar", 2);
tangoDown.execute();
```

Comment: Though I was looking for some Ebean methods without raw query, I guess that's not possible for the moment.